# SQL count and join from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, count

There is a product table which contains all the product details. A product can be nominated to the popular table from where different people can vote on it. i need to count only the votes of registered users. Currently it is counting all the votes that a particular product has. How do i overcome this problem? i have pasted my sql code below:

```
SELECT popular.name, popular.product_id, product.text, product.author, count(        vote.product_id ) AS votes
FROM popular
LEFT JOIN product ON ( product.id = popular.product_id )
LEFT JOIN vote ON ( vote.product_id = popular.product_id )
where popular.hidden = '1' and
popular.name in (select registered.name from registered 
where registered.course_id='".$course_id."' and 
registered.section = '".$section."' and 
registered.term = '".$term."')
GROUP BY popular.product_id
ORDER BY votes DESC Limit 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a join between votes and your other tables

```
Select P.ID, P.text, count(v.Product_ID) as votes
FROM Product PRO
LEFT JOIN Popular Pop
  ON PRO.ID = Pop.Product_ID
LEFT JOIN VOTE V   --<-- This is missing
  on V.Product_ID = Pro.ID
Group by P.ID, Pro.Text
order by votes Desc
```

Comment: i need to modify this slightly. i need to count the votes only by registered users but the popular products can be voted on by any user. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pop.product_id, pd.text, count( vt.product_id ) AS votes
FROM popular pop
LEFT JOIN product pd ON(pd.product = pop.product_id)
LEFT JOIN vote vt ON(vt.product_id = pop.product_id)
WHERE 1 = 1 // or pop.product_id = yourProductId here
GROUP BY pop.product.id
ORDER BY vt.votes DESC
```

Comment: i need to modify this slightly. i need to count the votes only by registered users but the popular products can be voted on by any user. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT popular.product_id, product.text, count( vote.product_id ) AS votes
FROM popular, product, vote
WHERE product.id = popular.product_id AND product.id = vote.product_id
GROUP BY product.id
ORDER BY votes DESC
```

Note that this query does not return products having no votes. If there are such records in your DB, you should `LEFT JOIN` with `vote` table.